# Do-While iteration approach determine by threshold

Tags: java, do-while

I have a question using Java do-while loop to determine when to stop by a threshold (MinRevChange in the code).

The larger loop will stop when the value difference between 2 closest data points is below the threshold (DfDi < MinRevChange); and the loop within it will stop when Q is greater than n (30 in this example).

```
private static int OBMethod33(double mean, double MinRevChange) {

    double RmRev = 399;
    double BenchPrice = 486;

    int n = 30;
    int i = 0;

    double Fcurr = 0;
    double Fopt = 0;
    double Fprev = 0;
    double DfDi = 999999;

    do {
        Fcurr = 0;

        int Q = 0;
        do {
            Fcurr = Fcurr
                + RmRev * (Math.pow(mean, Q) * Math.exp(-mean) / factorialRecursive(Q)) * Math.max(Q - i, 0)
                + BenchPrice * (Math.pow(mean, Q) * Math.exp(-mean) / factorialRecursive(Q))
                            * Math.max(i - Q, 0);
            Q++;
        } while (Q <= n);

        DfDi = Math.abs(Fcurr - Fprev);
        Fopt = Fcurr;
        Fprev = Fcurr;

        i++;

    } while ((i <= 10) && (DfDi >= MinRevChange));

    return i - 1;

}

private static long factorialRecursive(int i) {

    if (i < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (i < 2)
        return i * 1;

    return i * factorialRecursive(i - 1);
}
```

Based on Poisson Distribution pmf function: [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)
which is the code (Math.pow(mean, Q) * Math.exp(-mean) / factorialRecursive(Q))
As Q increases to n, 'Fcurr' will be added for each Q.

DfDi is calculated by deducting the value of two 'i's: 'Fcurr' and 'Fprev'.

The second function returns factorial of a number i! = 1 * 2 * ... * i; used to calculate Poisson Distribution pmf.

Given an example of (mean, MinRevChange) = (6.2, 250) it returns 10; 
while I validated the example and function using SAS, it should return 5.

I think within the first function, it seems the 'DfDi >= MinRevChange' condition is not used;  How can I modify it? Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: "while it should return 5." what makes you think so? BTW how many times do you expect `int i = 0; do{ something(); i++; }while(i <= 1);` to call `something()` (to iterate)?

Comment: One of the exit conditon would be that `i > 10` and since you return `i -1` that explain the returned value of `10`. Now, if you expect that your loop exit because of `DfDi > MinRevChange`, then you have a problem of algorithm but this is not explained enought to review this. Try to propose a [mcve] please by [edit]ing your question. **EDIT:** Of course, you are using `double` ... so it might be a simple floating-precision problem... **EDIT2:** please call `factorialRecursive(Q)` only once before this long math operation ... and use the result of it.

Comment: @Pshemo I run the same function and example under SAS, and it will return 5. It seems `DfDi >= MinRevChange` condition is not used. And `int i = 0;` is the initial value I set for i that starts calculation.  Thanks!

Comment: I am just wandering if you are aware of fact that  code like `int i = 0; do{ something(); i++; }while(i <= 1);` will iterate 2 times, not 1 time (do it on paper to see what value `i` holds and when, especially at `while(i <= 1);` which decides if loop should iterate again). For same reason your `int Q = 0; do { Fcurr = ...; Q++; } while (Q <= n);` will iterate `n+1` times. Usually if we start iterating with `counter` initialized to 0 inside condition we use `counter < N` instead of `counter <= N` (assuming `N` is representing amount of expected iterations).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks! Right I would like to start from like (Q=0). which is n+1 times.

Comment: @AxelH Thanks I just updated the description is it clearer now?

Comment: @Pshemo Is there any way to print the 'DfDi' value for each i within the function? So that I could check if this condition is used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
private static int OBMethod33(double mean, double MinRevChange) {

double RmRev = 399;
double BenchPrice = 486;

int n = 30;
int i = 0;

double Fcurr = 0;
double Fopt = 0;
double Fprev = 0;
double DfDi = 999999;

do {
    Fcurr = 0;

    int Q = 0;
    do {
        Fcurr = Fcurr
            + RmRev * (Math.pow(mean, Q) * Math.exp(-mean) / factorialRecursive(Q)) * Math.max(Q - i, 0)
            + BenchPrice * (Math.pow(mean, Q) * Math.exp(-mean) / factorialRecursive(Q))
                        * Math.max(i - Q, 0);
        Q++;
    } while (Q <= n);

    DfDi = Math.abs(Fcurr - Fprev);
    Fopt = Fcurr;
    Fprev = Fcurr;

    i++;

// This line added to print out the result after each iteration;
    System.out.println("DfDi = " + DfDi + " :: Fcurr = " + Fcurr);  

} while ((i <= 10) && (DfDi >= MinRevChange));

return i - 1;
```

}

private static long factorialRecursive(int i) {

```
if (i < 0) {
    return -1;
}

if (i == 0) {
    return 1;
}

if (i < 2)
    return i * 1;

return i * factorialRecursive(i - 1);
```

It works by setting value pairs of (mean, MinRevChange).

Thanks!